# Ellipsis broadcasting in numpy.einsum

Tags: python, numpy, ellipsis, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I'm having a problem understanding why the following doesn't work:

I have an array *prefactor* that can be three-dimensional or six-dimensional.
I have an array *dipoles* that has four dimensions. The first three dimensions of *dipoles* match the last three dimensions of *prefactor*.

As I don't know the shape of *prefactor*, I'm using an Ellipsis to account for the three optional dimensions in *prefactor*:

```
numpy.einsum('...lmn,lmno->...o', prefactor, dipoles)
```

(In the example here, prefactor.shape is (1, 1, 1, 160, 160, 128) and dipoles.shape is (160, 160, 128, 3). When executing, I get the error:

**operand 1 did not have enough dimensions to match the broadcasting, and couldn't be extended because einstein sum subscripts were specified at both the start and end**

It does work, however, when I add an ellipsis to the second term as well:

```
numpy.einsum('...lmn,...lmno->...o', prefactor, dipoles)
```

Just that I don't understand why, because there should be no need for an ellipsis there. Does someone know what's going on here?

The same question has been asked at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/53705 but there is no satisfactory answer yet.

Answer (score 5):

There is a github issue for this problem:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2455
improvement of index notation in einsum (Trac #1862)

Error case:

```
einsum('ij...,j->ij...',A,B)
```

Current work around requires (empty) ellipsis:

einsum('ij...,j...->ij...',A,B)

It looks like `einsum` loops through the string argument and the ops several times, identifying the indexes, and broadcast types (right, left, middle, none), and op dimensions.  With this it constructs an `numpy.nditer`.  It's while constructing `op_axes` for the nditer that `einsum` raises this error.  I don't know if the test criteria is too tight (`ibroadcast >= ndim`), or if it needs to take an additional step to construct the right `op_axes` for this argument.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2619 shows how `nditer` can be used to replicate `einsum` behavior.  Working from this I can replicate your calculation thus:

```
prefactor = np.random.random((1, 1, 1, 160, 160, 128))
dipoles = np.random.random((160, 160, 128, 3))
x = numpy.einsum('...lmn,...lmno->...o', prefactor, dipoles)
#numpy.einsum('...lmn,lmno->...o', prefactor, dipoles)  # not work

op_axes = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,-1], [-1,-1,-1,0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,-1,-1,-1,3]]
flags = ['reduce_ok','buffered', 'external_loop', 'delay_bufalloc', 'grow_inner']
op_flags = [['readonly']]*nops + [['allocate','readwrite']]
it = np.nditer([prefactor,dipoles,None], flags, op_flags, op_axes=op_axes)
it.operands[nops][...] = 0
it.reset()
#it.debug_print()
for (x,y,w) in it:
    w[...] += x*y
print "\nnditer usage:"
print it.operands[nops] # == x
print it.operands[nops].shape # (1, 1, 1, 3)
```

The `op_axes` line is indicative of what `einsum` deduces from `'...lmn,...lmno->...o'`.

---

I am exploring this issue on https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum.

There I have a `einsum_py.py` which emulates `np.einsum` with Python code.  The part that is relevant to this issue is `parse_subscripts()`, and in particular `prepare_op_axes()`.  It appears that only the `BROADCAST_RIGHT` iteration (starting from the end) is needed to correctly create `op_axes`, regardless of where ellipses are in the subscripts.  It also removes the error message that is at the core of this issue.

The `einsum.c.src` file on that repository has this change, and compiles correctly with the current master distribution (just replace the file and build).  It tests fine against `test_einsum.py`, as well as examples from this issue.

I've submitted a pull request for this change.