# numpy einsum with '...'

Tags: python, numpy

The code below is meant to conduct a linear coordinate transformation on a set of 3d coordinates. The transformation matrix is `A`, and the array containing the coordinates is `x`. The zeroth axis of `x` runs over the dimensions x, y, z. It can have any arbitrary shape beyond that.

Here's my attempt:

```
A = np.random.random((3, 3))
x = np.random.random((3, 4, 2))

x_prime = np.einsum('ij,j...->i...', A, x)
```

The output is:

```
    x_prime = np.einsum('ij,j...->i...', A, x)

ValueError: operand 0 did not have enough dimensions
to match the broadcasting, and couldn't be extended
because einstein sum subscripts were specified at both
the start and end
```

If I specify the additional subscripts in `x` explicitly, the error goes away. In other words, the following works:

```
x_prime = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', A, x)
```

I'd like `x` to be able to have any arbitrary number of axes after the zeroth axis, so the workaround I give about is not optimal. I'm actually not sure why the first `einsum` example is not working. I'm using numpy 1.6.1. Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)?

Comment: FWIW your code seems to work as-is in numpy 1.9.0.dev-b785070.

Comment: I've noticed at least one other bug with einsum in my version of numpy (incorrect results with three operands), so I wouldn't be surprised if this is a second bug. I think einsum was introduced in v1.6.0.

Comment: `x_prime = np.einsum('...ij,j...->i...', A, x)` should also work.  This issue was raised in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591696/ellipsis-broadcasting-in-numpy-einsum/`, and corrected in the latest code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's a bug. It was fixed in this pull request: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4099

This was only merged a month ago, so it'll be a while before it makes it to a stable release.

**EDIT**: As @hpaulj mentions in the comment, you can work around this limitation by adding an ellipsis even when all indices are specified:

```
np.einsum('...ij,j...->i...', A, x)
```

Comment: If you add the suggestion from @hpaulj's comment, this answer would be spot on. Other people will probably have the same problem for some time to come, since it will take a while for the next stable version of numpy to get included in the major distros (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS probably won't include it, CentOS takes ages to release new versions, etc.).