# Multiply (a x a) square matrix by (a x c x d) matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So let's say I have a list of `(c x d)` matrices.  Like say I have `a` of them.  And I have `a` coefficients for each matrix.

Is there a quick way in NumPy to scalar-multiply each matrix by its coefficient at once while still keeping the tensor data structure, or do I need to manually go through in a for loop i.e. `X = np.array([np.multiply(coefs[i], X[i]) for i in range(len(coefs))])`

i.e. `X.shape = (3, 4, 5)`, `coefs.shape = (3)`.

Comment: Can you clarify by writing a mathematical formula of what you want?

Comment: Your examples ```X.shape, coeffs.shape``` are 3-D and 1-D - this conflicts with the title ... 2-D times 3-D.

Comment: Alternate for your list comprehension: ```[np.multiply(a, b) for a, b in zip(X, coeffs)]```

Comment: @Andrew, wondering if you ended up considering my suggestion, `np.einsum`, then?

Comment: Hey!  I appreciate you writing the answer, but unfortunately, as you mentioned, for large datasets there is not a big speed increase and for a one-off use like what I am doing, the versatility is not a major advantage.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X = np.array([[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]],
              [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]],
              [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]])

coeffs = np.array([2,4,6])
```

You need to add axes to `coeffs` so it will broadcast in the dimension(s) you want.

```
>>> X * coeffs[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
array([[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]])
>>>
```

The `np.newaxis`'s allow the values of `coeffs` to line up with the first dimension of `X` and then they are [broadcast](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/numpy.html#broadcasting) across the remaining dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

This is the classic problem of going the pythonic way. Following 1-liner does the trick using the powerful `einstein sum`, [np.einsum()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), function with the rich framework of subscript labels that allow for [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) of dimensions and controlling the output:

```
np.einsum('ijk,i...->ijk', X, coeffs)
```

**Subscript String:**

- Comma `,` separates out the subscript labels for the first operand, on the left, from that of the second operand, to the right.
- Subscript label after the `->` symbol gives the dimensions of the output.
- Ellipsis `...` would allow for broadcasting the `coeffs` vector into the extra 2 dimensions of the `X` matrix (`...` is actually optional for a more explicit specification of broadcasting)

It takes a little getting used to but has many matrix-vector operations, like `trace`, `diag`, `inner/outer product`, `element-wise multiplication`, etc., all lumped into this powerful formulation.

**In words:**

So the string essentially says that take all the dimensions of `X` matrix and multiply it element-wise with the `coeffs` vector (broadcasted across the extra dimensions of `X`) and generate an output matrix of the same dimensions as that of `X`.

**Output:**

```
>>> np.einsum( 'ijk,i->ijk', np.ones((2,2,2)), np.array([2,4]))

array([[[ 2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.]],

       [[ 4.,  4.],
        [ 4.,  4.]]])
```

In the 2D case, elementwise along either axes:

```
>>> np.einsum( 'ij,i->ij', np.ones((2,2)), np.array([2,4]))
array([[ 2.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  4.]]) 

>>> np.einsum( 'ij,j->ij', np.ones((2,2)), np.array([2,4]))
array([[ 2.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  4.]])
```

**Alternative:**

Offcourse you can manually broadcast the vector across extra dimensions using `np.newaxis` parameter and simple multiplication:

```
X * coeff[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
```

**Timing:**

Using ipython line magic function `%timeit` we can actually see that the `einsum` might be a little more expensive for large data sets:

```
>>> %timeit np.einsum('ijk,i...->ijk',np.ones((10,100,100)),np.ones(10))
1000 loops, best of 3: 209 µs per loop

>>> %timeit np.ones((10,100,100))*np.ones(10)[:,np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
1000 loops, best of 3: 129 µs per loop
```

Tradeoff then is in the versatility that the `einstein sum` offers.

*P.S.* If you are a Matlab user obsessed with the rich indexing framework that it provides, you may be interested in checking this [Numpy-Matlab comparison](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) page out

Comment: `'ijk,i->ijk'` also works.  So does `'i...,i->i...'`.  Contrary to earlier `einsum` documentation, ellipsis doesn't allow broadcasting (that's always allowed), rather it is a place holder for unnamed dimensions.

Comment: agreed that the use of ellipsis is rather optional. However, `i...,i->i...` representation doesn't work for me.

Comment: Is `'i...,i->i...'` giving an error?  It used to object about a missing  ellipsis.  But that's been patched in recent version(s).

Comment: Here's the error: `ValueError: operand 1 did not have enough dimensions to match the broadcasting, and couldn't be extended because einstein sum subscripts were specified at both the start and end`

Comment: Regarding your `Alternative` statement: is this ```einsum``` notation doing anything other than simple multiplication while broadcasting one operand across the extra dimensions of another and was the notation somehow arrived at *automagically* rather than *manually*?

Comment: @wwii yes with this construct it is doing exactly that. I don't understand your second question about arriving at this notation "automagically" vs. "manually"? By the usage of the word "manually", I actually meant that with `einsum` you don't have to explicitly specify across how many dimensions should the second operand be broadcasted. It will take care of it for you.

Comment: More on that `einsum` error from last year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591696/ellipsis-broadcasting-in-numpy-einsum/  Version 1.9 should have the patch.